# Javascript: Rewrite anchor or hash to ampersand

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, anchor, ampersand

How can i rewrite part of an URL to alter the anchor or has tag to an ampersand? Example:

http://www.test.com/?database=demo#option=set

changed to:

..website../?database=demo&option=set

Notice the change from #option to &option.

I know the # is only processed client side (it never reaches server), so Javascript seemed like the only way to go.

Can Javascript change this on the fly, even without reloading the page? That would eliminate an IF check to find if an instance exists. A reload if the page would work to1...

Thanks for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Can Javascript change this on the fly, even without reloading the page?"

No. What you think is a cosmetic change, in reality means totally different resource as represented by URL, because `&option` would mean new GET parameter.

So page redirect would be needed in order to change this part of URL.

Comment: I understand that the processing is done on totally different locations. # is client side, while & does get delivered to the server. The solutions i was seeking has had a totally different solution. I send the variables using both & and # so that they get processed on both sides, in Javascript and PHP. Thank you for the explanation.